# how to implement decrypt in flutter like java?

Tags: java, flutter

I have to change java code for decrypt to flutter code. I use library "encrypt" for flutter. my flutter code show

> Key length not 128/192/256 bits.

my java spring boot code.

```
public static String decryptAES256(String str, String secretKey) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException,
                NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
                InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
            String AES = "AES";
            String AES_PADDING = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
            byte[] keyData = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretKey);
            String iv = secretKey.substring(0, 16);
            SecretKey secureKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, AES);
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(AES_PADDING);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secureKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            byte[] byteStr = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str.getBytes());
            return new String(c.doFinal(byteStr), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
```

my flutter code.

```
final encData = codefModel.data!.encData!;
    final key = en.Key.fromUtf8(decryptKey);
    final b64key = en.Key.fromUtf8(base64Url.encode(key.bytes));
    final iv = en.IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = en.Encrypter(en.AES(b64key, mode: en.AESMode.cbc));
    logger.d(encrypter.decrypt64(encData, iv: iv));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java code it can be deduced that the AES key `secretKey` and the ciphertext `str` are Base64 encoded. The first 16 bytes of *the Base64 encoded* key (not of the *raw* key!) are used as IV.
In the Dart code the key is incorrectly converted and a wrong IV is used. A possible fix is (together with sample data):

```dart
const decryptKey = "MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDE=";
const encData = "lo0dOoJrHNRuefPXgkEa6jtDUhV5CguF9MHWTJ4Y8eGP8zHaKJEQIuOTZxstyk3X";
final key = en.Key.fromBase64(decryptKey);
final iv = en.IV(Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(decryptKey).sublist(0, 16)));
final encrypter = en.Encrypter(en.AES(key, mode: en.AESMode.cbc));
final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt64(encData, iv: iv); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

As test, key and ciphertext can be used in the Java code that returns the same plaintext for them.

---

Be aware that deriving the IV from the key is generally insecure, since encryptions with the same key automatically lead to the reuse of key/IV pairs. Instead, a random IV should be used for each encryption.

Comment: Thank you!!.. it's problem is iv!!! it's very helpful.